# Building custom API and using wp_get_nav_menu_items to get menu items. Only works when logged in, returns nothing when I'm not

Tags: menus, api, json

Working on a custom api for a site I'm building and I found a weird issue with wp_get_nav_menu_items.

Essentially - wp_get_nav_menu_items only works and returns items when I'm logged in. If I'm not it returns a blank array.

The menu items are supposed to basically just consist of some custom post types. No pages or anything else.

I've tried adding the `show_in_rest` property when registering the post type but this does not appear to have any effect.

Is there a way around this? Or is there another way I can pull all of the items added to a menu and spit out some json?

For reference this is what the code I used to generate the json data for the menus looks like

```
function menu_route(){
   $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('HCH');

   $menu = array();
  foreach ($menu_items as $item ){

    $menuItem = array(

        "title"=>$item->title,
        "dom_id"=>preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i',"_",$item->title)
    );

    array_push($menu,$menuItem);
  }
  return $menu; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what happened but things appear to be working for some reason. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ consider this answered.